# ips tag says "intrusion detection system"?

Tags: discussion

[image: screeenshot]

As you can see from the screenshot the `ips` tag says intrusion detection when mouse is hovered over the tag and when I clicked on the tag to edit the wiki it takes me to the right tag that is `ids`.

Theoretically these two are different terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, IPS - aka Intrustion Protection System - and IDS (Intrustion Detection System) are similar products, with a similar set of technologies.
IPS really is the evolution of IDS, and almost all (I think maybe all) IDS vendors have rebranded their offerings as IPS.

That is why [ips](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ips) is a synonym for [ids](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ids), as is [intrusion-detection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intrusion-detection).

Comment: ohk..I was thinking from a theoretical point of view

Comment: Well theoretically, these can both be considered part of IDPS, or even one a subset of the other. Realistically, the difference is really just a small question of feature-set, or even more often a question of marketing-speak. Like e.g. the difference between IdM and IAM - yesterday's IdM is today's IAM.